# How to generate .resx and .properties files from the same XLIFF translation file

Tags: c#, java, localization, internationalization

In order to minimize the localization efforts I would like to be able to re-use the same translations for all the projects within the company. The problem is that projects are developed in different languages, to be particular **C#** and **Java**.

As I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508066/xliff-versioning-or-translation-updates-process) the handy tool I found for **xliff** extraction and merging is *Okapi Rainbow* - but so far it looks that this tool can post-process xliff translation only into original format the xliff was extracted from. So if xliff was extracted from **resx** - there seems to be no obvious way to get Java .**properties** as output.

Am I missing a simple step? If I don't have the original file at all - is there a way to generate **resx/properties** files directly from **xliff**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okapi needs the original file to generate the target file from XLIFF.

Among others because the XLIFF extract only the localizable part from a file. If you look at a resx file, the <xsd:schema> and <resheader> don't get extracted. So there is no way to generate back a resx file without a "skeleton"

Also, I would not go thru XLIFF to map between properties and resx. Among other you might want to do that for English too.

It should be relatively easy thought to convert between .properties and resx directly.
For instance `resgen foo.resx foo.txt` will convert foo.resx to foo.txt, which is very much like a Java properties file, except that is is UTF-8 (so you can just use native2ascii).

Or you can write your own simple convertor (using ResXResourceReader and ResXResourceReader).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to convert the .resx files into .property files or vice versa as the CAT tool your translators use will store the sentences in an intermediate format, e.g. tmx to match the source sentences.